# Can Node.js be used across computers with and without it being installed?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

So, I'm making a quiz, and I've been wanting to save my answers to a text file. I want to use "*Node.js*", and I'm worried about this: They only offer an installer to *install* Node.js on your computer. Since I'm not working with servers or anything like that, and I'm just a hobbyist, the people I might first give this to may not have Node.js installed on their computer. Please do note that this is for a website, not a program.

Is there any way I can make this work across computers without Node.js installed?

***Thanks for any help!***

Comment: Have you looked into docker ?

Comment: it depends on the nature of your quiz, there are certain hosting services that can do a lot of that for free (they host node) or if app is limited to serving static files you could use something different than node

Comment: Across Windows computers? Or is it supposed to also work on Linux and Macs? Since you have already excluded using a server, which is the obvious and simple answer to create an interface for all platforms: even Java, which is built to run everywhere, requires the JRE to be installed. There's also heroku, where you can host a node app "for free", and github pages, where you can a static website for free.

Comment: ChrisG, Across all sorts of users: Windows/Mac/Linux/Android/iOS/iPadOS/etc., etc., you get the idea. Why am I not using a server? Because I'm in 8th grade. I'll use servers when my school accepts my program as a better alternative.           BARNOWL, I will look into it.        Krzysztof Krzeszewski, the program is supposed to get, edit, save to a text document.

Comment: If the "Quiz Interface" is a desktop application I would suggest you take a look at https://www.electronjs.org/.

Comment: With a requirement like that, a website is the only reasonable way forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, You should look at various server frameworks. Nodejs is not only the one best. Others, like Django of python can be a better choice.

Secondly, Web Application created by any (Till I Know) Framework required to be installed but no big deal. You can install it in school computer, it's not that heavy software. Some Schools may also use firewall to restrict any unknown web sites to lab. So some free hosting site may not work in lab.

A most right choice must be to install nodejs in your school computers. But you must try Heroku, It's definitely the best free hosting site.

Edit at 31july:
Solely Packing nodejs project is not always the best choice because sometimes session handler database run in memory and it require another tools to be installed in computer. Like reds-server in case of redis database.

There's an other option you can check. It's 'Docker'.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can compile an app made with Nodejs to an executable. Running that executable will not need anything preinstalled. There are many options to do that but I personnally like PKG.

https://github.com/vercel/pkg